# trello api custom labels creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, trello

I followed the Trello API documentation for custom label but id didn't work

I'm using ruby-trello gem

```
  label_data = {
    'name' => "testing",
    'idBoard' => board,
    'color' => "green"
  }

  label = client.post("/labels", label_data)
```

the label created succesfully and I saw it in the board, but when I use the format of creating bug and pass the label id  to the idLabels   attr   it create the card without the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this hack instead of the regular api

```
label_response = client.post("/cards/#{card.id}/idLabels",{value: label_id})
```